# Add Zero to dates

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get a 4 digit date with a '/' in the middle. I have it all working, except on days that are single digit.

Example:
12/03 gets displayed as 12/3. My question is, if its a single digit, is there a way to add a zero to the front.

Current code:

```
Dim month As Integer = Now.Month
Dim day As Integer = Now.Day
TDate.Text = month & "/" & day
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd")
```

If you want to update your existing code, this should help.

```
Dim month As Integer = DateTime.Now.Month
Dim day As Integer = DateTime.Now.Day
Dim a = month & "/" & day.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)
```

Comment: Worked perfect, I will accept as answered when timer is up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is where you would use format strings, i.e.

```
Date.Now.ToString("MM/dd")
```

MSDN reference on date/time format strings:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx